Watching changes in MongoDB in KTOR
I need to listen to changes in MongoDb using KTOR.
I've tried Change Streams but can not implement it somehow. Could you please tell me other solutions or using Change Streams in a proper way. I don't want to use firebase anymore.
fun Application.launchChangeStreamWatcher(collection: MongoCollection<UserData>) {
launch {
    val changeStream = collection.watch().iterator()
    while (changeStream.hasNext()) {
        val changeEvent = changeStream.next()
        println("Received change event: $changeEvent")
    }
}



 fun Application.module() {

    val collection by inject<MongoCollection<UserData>>()
    launchChangeStreamWatcher(collection)
}

I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: |- No definition found for class:'com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection'. Check your definitions!

What have you tried and what is not working out?

@ILyaCyclone I couldn't find anywhere how to implement change streams in KTOR, even chatgbt couldn't help me. I get too many errors

Can you try to implement that without using Koin?
